# How to fix proxies for selenium with chromedriver and python

Tags: python, selenium, python-requests

Proxies work with requests library but not selenium, however selenium is fully functional when not using proxies.

I've tried many recommendations from stackoverflow about how to use proxies with selenium. The most common being what I've pasted in the code snippet. However everytime I use this the request fails.

The proxies are definitely operational as work through requests library.

When I remove the proxy argument from chrome options, then it works fine but not with the proxy argument.

Can anyone recommend some help

```
proxy = 'MY_PROXY_GOES_HERE'
url = 'https://google.co.uk/'

# Try with selenium 

driver_path = "chromedriver"
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument(f'--proxy-server={proxy}')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driver_path, chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.implicitly_wait(30)  # seconds
driver.get(url=url)

# Try with requests

proxies = {'https': proxy}
response = requests.get(url, proxies=proxies)
```

Comment: How does the request fail? Please provide a traceback

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and it works, see below. I only added a random proxy server.
Depending on what exception you get, a possible guess is that the implicit wait causes a timeout. So I removed that from the code below. If you (still?) get a timeout try changing the default page timeout (`driver.set_page_load_timeout(xxx)`) to something higher, default is 60s for chromedriver.

```
from selenium import webdriver

proxy = 'http://202.60.227.65:57887'
url = 'https://google.co.uk/'

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument(f'--proxy-server={proxy}')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
driver.get(url=url)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply - the issue turned out to be selenium isn't able to handle username and password in the proxy url without extra work.